# return statement in boolean method

Tags: java, methods, boolean, return

I do not understand what I should return. My method returns false if the last time it goes
through the for-loop it is false. If the last time is true than it returns true. But I want it to return false regardless of where the false occurred.

```
    public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int number = 4;
            int[] intArray = {4, 8, 12, 16};
            System.out.println(allMultipleOf(intArray, number));
        }
```

```
        public static boolean allMultipleOf(int[] ary, int n){
            boolean a = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){
                if(ary[i] % n == 0){
                    a = true;
                    //System.out.println(a);
                    break;
                } else {
                    a = false;
                }
            }
    }
        return a; //what should I return
}
```

Comment: Once you first find a false case you return false. If you never find a false case, return true. You don't need `a` or the `break`, you can return from inside your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return false early from the method, if we reached the end without returning false, then return true:

```
public static boolean allMultipleOf(int[] ary, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if (ary[i] % n != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should `return false`, the default of the boolean is print at this place.

You can make the return statement within the method. it return true.

```
public static boolean allMultipleOf(int[] ary, int n) {
  boolean a = true;
  for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    if (ary[i] % n == 0) {
      a = true;
      //System.out.println(a);
      break;
    } else {
      a = false;
    }
  } 
  return a; 
}
```